# Windows Service with Service Stack returns "Bad Request" Error

Tags: c#, windows-services, runtime-error, servicestack

I am trying to create a windows service with service stack. The service runs without problems. But as soon as I send a request I get a bad request error.

I tried client.get, client.post and client.send. This always returns the bad request error.

The Client:

> ```
> using ServiceStack;
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Text;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
> using WindowsService1.ServiceModel;
>
> namespace ConsoleApp1
> {
> class Program
> {
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://127.0.0.1:8088").WithCache();
>
>             var result = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "Test"});
>
>             Console.WriteLine(result.Result);
>         }
>         catch (WebServiceException webEx)
>         {
>             Console.Error.WriteLine(webEx.StatusCode);
>             Console.Error.WriteLine(webEx.StatusDescription);
>             Console.Error.WriteLine(webEx.ErrorCode);
>             Console.Error.WriteLine(webEx.ErrorMessage); //Is Empty.
>             Console.Error.WriteLine(webEx.StackTrace);
>         }
>     }
> }}
> ```

The Service:

Is a Template from ServiceStack. (ServiceStack Windows Service Empty).

The problem I have only with Windows service.

Comment: This just means your Service Request failed, you need to find the cause of the Exception, I’d recommend using a HTTP packet sniffer like Fiddler so you can view the full raw Http Error Response.

Comment: Fiddler jeah. I try it tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: It's an Invalid Hostname problem. Has been fixed. Thanks to mythz.